# What is the probability that the distance between x and y is less than d?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Let $w$ and $d$ be positive real numbers. A point $x$ and a point $y$ are selected at random from the closed interval $[0,w]$ of the real number line. What is the probability that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $d$? (Your answer should be a formula in terms of $w$ and $d$.)

**My solution :**
The distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $d$ if and only if $|x - y| < d$. Geometrically, this means that we are looking for the probability that the points $x$ and $y$ lie within a strip of width $2d$ centered on the diagonal of the square $[0,w] \times [0,w]$.

The diagonal has length $\sqrt(w^2 + w^2) = \sqrt(2)w$, so the area of the square is $w^2$, and the area of the strip is $2dw$.

Thus, the probability that $|x - y| < d$ is the ratio of the area of the strip to the area of the square:

$P(|x - y| < d)$ = (area of strip) / (area of square) = $\frac{2dw}{w^2} = \frac{2d}{w}$.

Therefore, the probability that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $d$ is $2d/w$

Is my solution correct?.

Thank you.

Comment: If $d=\frac w2$ your answer is $1$.  Does that make sense?  If $d=w$ your answer is $2$.

Comment: @lulu I wanted to draw but since $d$ is arbitrary, I cannot see how I can draw subregion of the points for which $|x-y|<d$.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I noticed that you already described that picture.  But note that it's hard to see the area of the desired strip directly. The complement of that strip, however, is just the disjoint union of two right triangles, so it is easy to read off the area.  I get $1-\frac {(w-d)^2}{w^2}$ in the end.  Note that at least this gives the right answer for $d=0$ and $d=w$.

Comment: This can also be solved by considering the probability density function of the quantity $|x-y|$ (a one-sided tent function) and performing an integration.

Comment: Are we meant to assume that $d\le w$?

Comment: Here's a Desmos picture of the situation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cidcdebhvr